# Collision Detection pygame

Tags: vector, pygame, collision

im currently making a small game by following youtube tutorials. i followed this tutorial by Clear code for the movement: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4aZe84vvE20&t=230s&ab_channel=ClearCode
i wanted to take my game to the next level and add a few blocks around the map which the user has to avoid. i want to make it so that if the car hits a block it stops and only moves when the user rotates it to face away from the block, into an empty space. right now, in the player class, ive created a collision attribute and have used pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, blocks, True) to check for collision. the blocks variable is a group containing all the sprites for the blocks.
if there is a collision, i change the vector to (0,0), which stops the car, like intended. however, i cant figure out a way to change the vector again once ive rotated the car so that it faces away from the block, to get it going again. any help is appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do not change the motion vector to (0, 0). As soon as a collision is detected, change the position of the car so that the car only touches the object but does not intersect the object.

Something like (pseudo code):

```
if collide_at_left_side:
   car.rect.left = obstacle.rect.right
```

A more general solution would be to correct the position along the normal vector of the collision.